# Check ViewStateEncryptionMode Programmatically

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, viewstate

How can I check `ViewStateEncryptionMode` programmatically, I just need to know what is the value of `ViewStateEncryptionMode` set. Does any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to check the property from the Page object?

something like this :

```
Page.ViewStateEncryptionMode
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.web.ui.page.viewstateencryptionmode(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That's worked, but why I don't have intellisense on this property?

Comment: I don't know, i can see it in my Visual Studio 2012...If it helped you, mark my response as answer please ;)